# iOS 11 Prevent Screen Record like Netflix

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios11, screen-recording

I have video playing in my application which I don't want to be recorded.  What **Netflix** application do is that they let the audio capture but not the video while screen is being recorded.

Anyone have idea how to implement this feature?

Comment: Tell me more about it? Your question lacks explanation.

Comment: i just simply don't want new iOS feature SCREEN RECORD to record video when my application is playing video.Netflix let's you record video within their application but as soon as you play any movie they only let record audio and for video they just put a last capture video frame before video was played

Answer (score 5):

You can listen for a `UIScreenCapturedDidChange` notification.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(screenCaptureChanged), name: NSNotification.Name.UIScreenCapturedDidChange, object: nil)
```

This is called when iOS 11 screen recording begins and ends. When the user is recording the screen, you can modify the UI to block any content that you don't want recorded.

This notification is fired when `UIScreen`'s `isCaptured` property changes. You can also inspect this property yourself:

```
UIScreen.main.isCaptured
```

Answer (score 5):

I believe, Netflix takes advantage of the "FairPlay Streaming" technology provided by Apple. According to [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1970/_index.html)

> If your application uses FairPlay Streaming (FPS) your video content
> will automatically not be captured by the iOS 11 screen recording
> feature or QuickTime Player on macOS. The portion of your application
> that is playing the content will be blacked out.
>
> **Note**: FairPlay Streaming will only provide protection for the video
> portion of your content. To prevent capture of the audio portion you
> should still use the UIScreen APIs discussed in this document to
> provide an appropriate message to the user if screen capture begins.

One can get an in-depth understanding of FPS from the link below :

https://developer.apple.com/streaming/fps/

Any application can incorporate FPS in order to achieve same results as Netflix.

Comment: This is absolutely the expected response. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I create a black view and add it at the top of UIWindow. Then, in view controller of PlayerVideo, create the observer

`NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(screenCaptureChanged), name: NSNotification.Name.UIScreenCapturedDidChange, object: nil)`

Then, in `screenCaptureChanged`:

```
(void) screenCaptureChanged {
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    BOOL isCaptured = [[UIScreen mainScreen] isCaptured];

    if (isCaptured) {
        self.blackView.hidden = false;
    }
    else {
        self.blackView.hidden = true;
    }
}
```

}

This solution will block the PlayerVideo when user is recording. However, I would like to create something like Netflix did. I want to let users do whatever they want while watching movie. If they are recording, they can continue watching video without black view. However, when they stop recording, the video will be save with black view. I'm still figuring out how Netflix did like this.

Comment: have you found any solution same like as Netflix do ?

Comment: Please check my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56005122/3496660

Answer (score 0):

Netflix solution is NOT about the code. It is called DRM or Digital Rights Management. It protects the data from any piracy. Including screen records/shots and downloading. Man, it's expensive.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make the following changes in your **Appdelegate.swift** page.

It will automatically adds a blurred view on the top of the app when the user tries to record the screen.

```
weak var screen : UIView? = nil

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(preventScreenRecording), name: UIScreen.capturedDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
    return true
}

@objc func preventScreenRecording() {
    let isCaptured = UIScreen.main.isCaptured
    print("isCaptured: \(isCaptured)")
    if isCaptured {
        blurScreen()
    }
    else {
        removeBlurScreen()
    }
}

func blurScreen(style: UIBlurEffect.Style = UIBlurEffect.Style.regular) {
    screen = UIScreen.main.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: false)
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: style)
    let blurBackground = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    screen?.addSubview(blurBackground)
    blurBackground.frame = (screen?.frame)!
    window?.addSubview(screen!)
}

func removeBlurScreen() {
    screen?.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Comment: There is one particular problem. It does not work if I start the screen recording on the home Screen and then open the app.
It does not detect that, what should we do about that scenario ???