# How to disable screen Recording in iOS app

Tags: ios, uiwindow, uiscreen

Is there any way to disable the screen recording? or is is possible through a configuration profile? or any third party library is available?

Comment: @PyaePhyoeShein without using blockView any solution?..

Comment: how about `self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red` or something else?

Comment: without interrupted my app user experience. only my app can avoid screen recordding ??.

Comment: show overlay popup with warning is the best.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(preventScreenRecording), name: NSNotification.Name.UIScreenCapturedDidChange, object: nil)
```

And create a view inside main view and prevent like that.

```
(void) preventScreenRecording {
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    BOOL isCaptured = [[UIScreen mainScreen] isCaptured];

    if (isCaptured) {
        self.blockView.hidden = false;
    }
    else {
        self.blockView.hidden = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what is blockView here? And I believe this method is called after screenshot is captured. I haven't tested it yet

Comment: @PPShein is there any way to disable screenshot?

Comment: @NightFury blockView is the area that you want to disable screenRecording.

Comment: @SagarDaundkar I think it would be same as what I mentioned.

Comment: could you please write as full code? thanks

Comment: Pls see https://stackoverflow.com/a/71170751/9978212, having complete code.

Answer (score 4):

When your app is started you can test `UIScreen.isCaptured` property and show some splash screen if it's set to `true`.

You should also observe (subscribe in some place for) `capturedDidChangeNotification` [notification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscreen/2921652-captureddidchangenotification), and do same thing (show splash screen) if `UIScreen.isCaptured` is set to `true`.

Comment: I am able to detect screen recoding using UIScreen.isCaptured.how to avoid screen recoding in my app without interrupted user experience of my app.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4 and above**

You just need to make the following changes in your **Appdelegate.swift** page.

It will automatically add a blurred view on the top of the app when the user tries to record the screen.

```
weak var screen : UIView? = nil

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(preventScreenRecording), name: UIScreen.capturedDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
    return true
}

@objc func preventScreenRecording() {
    let isCaptured = UIScreen.main.isCaptured
    print("isCaptured: \(isCaptured)")
    if isCaptured {
        blurScreen()
    }
    else {
        removeBlurScreen()
    }
}

func blurScreen(style: UIBlurEffect.Style = UIBlurEffect.Style.regular) {
    screen = UIScreen.main.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: false)
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: style)
    let blurBackground = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    screen?.addSubview(blurBackground)
    blurBackground.frame = (screen?.frame)!
    window?.addSubview(screen!)
}

func removeBlurScreen() {
    screen?.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sharedRecorder.stopRecording( handler: { previewViewController, error in    
    if let error = error {
        print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    if UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.pad {
        previewViewController?.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover
        previewViewController?.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect.zero
        previewViewController?.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
    }
    if previewViewController != nil {
        self.previewViewController = previewViewController
        previewViewController?.previewControllerDelegate = self
    }
    self.present(previewViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
    return
}



https://developer.apple.com/documentation/replaykit/rpscreenrecorder/1620990-stoprecording
```