# How to pause screen recording of a specific screen when user is using the screen recording tool from the control centre in iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, screen-recording

I want to automatically pause video screen recording when user navigates to a specific screen and resume when it pops-out but I don’t want to hinder user experience by hiding or blacking-out the current screen.

I know that iOS provides the required functionality for streaming apps only eg. Netflix, Prime etc. as they are using *FairPlay Streaming*.  For the Apps that uses FairPlay Streaming (FPS), their video content will automatically not be captured by the screen recording feature.

Is there any way to avoid video capturing for a normal screen same as FairPlay Streaming does on video content ?

Comment: Did you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53880658/6791677 ?

Comment: Yes, I tried it already, Its asking me to hide the current screen when i receive the notification but that would affect the user experience.