# How to prevent taking screen shoot in flutter IOS

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, flutter, flutter-ios

I've got an education flutter iOS app. and I want to prevent users to take screenshots or screen records on a specific screen and how to make it

I'm trying many solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52317217/flutter-disable-screenshot-capture-for-app#:%7E:text=1-,Flutter,-In%20Whole%20your) but no one is working

as attached below, it is a screen record form my iPhone from another app
it still records till I reach to specific screen and push me back and showing me this alert dialog
how to achieve this feature

[image: Screen Record]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable screen Recording in iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53880491/how-to-disable-screen-recording-in-ios-app)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent screen capture in an iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680028/prevent-screen-capture-in-an-ios-app)

Comment: no, I'm trying both and not working

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, APP Store Prevent this feature which is disable screenshot so we can work around to do this. my solution was to make user make an screen shot but with no data. I achieve it by this simple code

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import FirebaseCore

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  private var textField = UITextField()
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    self.window.makeSecure()
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
  // Screenshot Prevent Functions
 

      // <Add>
  override func applicationWillResignActive(
    _ application: UIApplication
  ) {
    self.window.isHidden = true;
  }
  override func applicationDidBecomeActive(
    _ application: UIApplication
  ) {
    self.window.isHidden = false;
  }

  
}
  extension UIWindow {
   func makeSecure() {
    let field = UITextField()
    field.isSecureTextEntry = true
    self.addSubview(field)
    field.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    field.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    self.layer.superlayer?.addSublayer(field.layer)
    field.layer.sublayers?.first?.addSublayer(self.layer)
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you try this and work ?

Comment: yes it's working well

Comment: This method will not allow you to upload the app to the app store.

Comment: @kunjkanani app already uploaded https://apps.apple.com/us/app/privilege/id1632963488

Answer (score -4):

Use this if you don't want users to take screenshots in your app.
[flutter_windowmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_windowmanager)

By using this package, you can add many more functionality like blur app when its in background, force full screen, dismiss keyguard.

Read the dicumentation for more info.

Comment: I'm asking about iOS not android